# Rails. Save pass parameter from action to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, user visiting home with invitation link `localhost:3000/home?invitation=invitation_token` and I want to keep in params while user is browsing site till he visit registration page.

I know there is possibility to add params to `link_to` method but there is to many where I need to put this and it's not possible to predict user behavior.

But what I'm looking it's custom method what I will place in `before_action` what will check if there is `params[:invitation]` and pass it to next, unpredictable, method.

PS. I know that I can save to cookies, but this is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mentioned cookies, but normally this would rely on the session. Have you consider  using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save it in a session variable such as `session[:invitation_token]`, otherwise you'll have to pass the param in every link. You can then use the variable directly such as:

```
before_action :check_token

def check_token
  redirect_to registration_url unless session[:invitation_token]
end
```

Comment: So there is no other was to 'keep' token in URL?